# How to use or translate a random forest model built using bigRF package in randomForest package?

Tags: r, random-forest

I have a random forest model built using the `bigrfc()` function of the `bigrf` package in `R`. I would like to use that model with the prediction function of `randomForest` package (the `predict.randomForest()` function).

Is there any way to directly use or translate the generated model with the `randomForest`'s functions?

Thanks.

Comment: I think its not possible as bigrf converts the data into big matrix and randomforest treats the categorical or factor variables as it is. To use big matrix we need to convert all categorical variables into numerical values.